# Is there any easy way to remote debug a swift (vapor/perfect/kitura) application running on an (develpoment) server?

Tags: swift, xcode, llvm, vapor, kitura

Using Xcode it’s quite easy to debug a server side swift (vapor/perfect/kitura) application running on the local machine. Unfortunately it’s not always easy to run a server application on the local workstations cause of datebase connections and various other interactions that are difficult to „emulate“ on a local machine. To make the application behave more like in production use, I would prefer to do some kind of remote debugging of the server side swift (vapor/perfect/kitura) application running on the server.

It seams like llvm is able to support remote-debugging. Is there any option to attache Xcode Debugger to the remote application (running on the server), or is there any other IDE capable of doing this?

Comment: There is https://github.com/RuntimeTools/SwiftMetrics, which isn't exactly what you are looking for. And I've not spent enough time to get it working. (It didn't work straight out of the box for me).

Answer (score -1):

My point of view is related to Vapor, but probably other frameworks also support it.

You can have different configurations for different environments, so I shouldn't be so hard to emulate production on development machine.

The only way to remote debug are log files. You can create your own logger - with vapor it is possible - and for "remote development build" you can have verbose logs. This is the only possible way which I know and recommend you.

You can consider this https://github.com/SwiftyBeaver/SwiftyBeaver